# Rails Migration - Constraints not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a new to Ruby on Rails (switched from Laravel) and don't understand how the migration constraints work.

In my migration file I have:

```
t.string :username, null: false, limit: 20
t.index :username, unique: true
```

But when I try to create a user with a username length that exceed the limit of 20 characters (or with no value), it works, only the unique constraint works and give me a warning if I try to create a second user with the same username.

I use sqlite for development. When I look into development.sqlite3 file, everything seems OK:

```
"username" varchar(20) NOT NULL
```

If someone could help me, it would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: For exceeding limit of 20 characters, SQLite ignores any length restriction.  Ref: [2.2 Affinity Name Examples](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  For "no value", have you checked your generated query, if you're passing an empty string then that would be valid for the defined constraints.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That explains everything...